# How to solve equation system with 3 parameters

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

How to solve this problem?

> $$y=2x^2-1$$
>   $$z=2y^2-1$$
>   $$x=2z^2-1$$

x,y,z - ?

I am not good at math. Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $$x=y=z=1$$ ${}$

Comment: @MrPie, is there any way of solution?

Answer (score 6):

Let $x=\cos A$ $$y=\cos2A,z=\cos4A,x=\cos8A$$

$$\cos8A=\cos A$$

$$8A=360^\circ n\pm A$$

Either $$(8+1)A=360^\circ n\implies A=40^\circ n;0\le n<180/40$$

What if $(8-1)A=360^\circ n?$

Comment: I am not sure  I follow properly but how do we get $x\in [-1,1]$ ? Or did you mean $x = \color{red}{r}\cos A$ ?

Comment: When $x>1 \lor x<-1,2x^2-1>x$, then $x<y<z<x$ which is false @TheDemonix_Hermit

Comment: $z=cos(4A)$ so $cos(8A)=cos(A)$ not $cos(4A)=cos(A)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, Is there any relation to the equation system?

Comment: @hgs, Thanks a lot for the observation

Comment: @Alisher, please pinpoint the point of confusion

Comment: I don't understand why you stop at $n=2$.  Don't we have $0\leq A<180^\circ$, so $0\leq n < 4.5$?  How do we produce the solution $x=y=z=-1/2$ without taking $n=3$?

Comment: @saulspatz, thanks for your observation

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}y &= 2x^2 - 1\tag{1}\\z &= 2y^2 - 1\tag{2}\\x &= 2z^2 - 1\tag{3}\end{align}$$

Substitute $(2)$ into $(3)$ to get
$$x = 2\left(2y^2 - 1\right)^2 - 1\tag{4}$$

You now have two simultaneous equations, i.e., $(1)$ and $(4)$, that you can solve to find the values of the variables $x$ and $y$. Once you have either of the two, finding the value of variable $z$ is trivial with either $(2)$ or $(3)$.

Comment: It is ok to set this equation, but would it be too complicated

Comment: True, but it is still a valid method.